# Umbrella term for organizations that help people?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

Is there a word besides `humanitarian` which we could use to describe any organization (non-profit, charity, volunteer, or otherwise) whose explicit purpose is to help people? Is that precisely what `humanitarian` is for?

I associate the phrase `humanitarian organization` with things like UNICEF and the Gates Foundation, and other big organizations that do their work at a large scale; I do not know if it should or should not apply to smaller organizations, or even to individuals who work towards goals that might be considered humanitarian.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: How broadly do you want to define "help people"? And what do you find inadequate about thesaurus suggestions like *charitable* or *philanthropic*? Note too that some terms have legal definitions in different countries.

Comment: `charitable` also works.

Comment: Pretty much all "NGOs" fall into this category.

Answer (score 2):

Any work marked by humanistic values and devotion to human welfare, regardless of its size and impact, could be termed "humanitarian".

> A humanitarian is a person concerned with the welfare of mankind.
>
> As an adjective, humanitarian is used to describe **something or
>   someone** who displays the characteristics of someone concerned with
>   human welfare.

- "The humanitarian project was developed to help women become self-sufficient in third world countries."

**(**[vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/humanitarian)**)**

Answer (score 1):

Best resource, bar none, for **finding and separating synonyms**, IMO:

[**Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms: A Dictionary of Discriminated** ...](https://books.google.ca/books?id=8N4UReTJYhUC&pg=PA140#v=onepage&q&f=false)

See **"charitable"** and related synonyms on pp. 140-141

Comment: Since links are unstable, it's best to provide an excerpt or summary of the external resource. This is true across StackExchange.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest "service organization".